# Which form of "ridiculous/ridiculously" is correct in this sentence, and why?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, gerund-phrases

This is the sentence in question:

**Never would he wish to injure the feelings of his schoolmate of so long ago, no matter how ridiculous/ridiculously he was acting, or how strange his beliefs.**

The difficulty seems to arise over figuring out if the verb phrase is *was acting*, or if the verb is *was*, which would make *acting ridiculous* a gerund--or not? Is this the key to figuring out the word form?

Does the author chose the word form in order to tell the reader when the *acting* was happening in time, or is one form always called for in this arrangement by some solid rule? If so, what IS this arrangement?

Comment: 'How ridiculous he was acting' = 'How ridiculous he was when acting' = 'How ridiculous he was when on the stage' is unacceptable here on semantic grounds. He was acting ridiculously. Substitute 'stupid / stupidly' for 'ridic...' in the original and see which sounds correct.

Comment: The "-ly" can be dropped. See related posts on this site.

Answer (score -1):

A gerund is not the same thing as a present participle even though both terms end in “-ing.”

A gerund always acts as a noun.

A present participle is always part of a verb phrase.

Examples:

> *Sarah enjoys singing.*
>   In this example, “Sarah” is the subject, “enjoys” is the verb, and “singing” is a noun acting as the direct object of the sentence(gerund).
>
> > *Sarah is singing*.
> >     In this example, “is singing” is the verb phrase. “Singing” is the present progressive verb, telling what the subject “Sarah” is doing.

Thus in *he was acting*, **was acting** acts as a verb phrase and **not a gerund**.

So,**ridiculously** is the right option as it is an adverb.

Comment: 'Ridiculously' is the correct choice, but the [gerund **or** past participle] analysis of _ing_-forms is not all that helpful, not least because 'gerund' has conflicting definitions. _Brown's deftly painting his daughter was a delight to watch._ illustrates why CGEL prefers to lump and ACGEL prefers a gradience.

Comment: "A gerund always acts as a noun." Huh?